# hide all div's (except first one) having same class

Tags: jquery

I have 10 <div>'s with a same class

```
 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c1"></div>
```

Now I need to hide all the <div> leaving first out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the fastest way to do it: `$('div.c1').not(':eq(0)').hide();` :)

Comment: @Brock Adams, Well jQuery docs say it's slower, but your :gt made me think of another method which is **much** faster according to your speed test. I added it as New way. I'll edit my post

Comment: @Brock Adams, actually when I test in FF 5 I get it the way the jQuery docs say as well. Maybe you just had a background task hog the CPU a little while you were testing or something.

Comment: @Brock right lol, oops. Of course that explains it haha. I fixed it now :)

Comment: Maybe so.  I notice on other browsers, and on FF without all my AdBlock, etc. plugins, that your speed assertions are correct.  Although the trivial speed differences are no reason to abandon the elegant beauty of my solution. (^_^)

Comment: @Brock I agree, in the real world you rarely need to hide a div more than once, let alone thousands of times per second :P

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.c1').hide();
$('.c1:first').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$('div.c1:gt(0)').hide ();
```

Which is more flexible, if you decide to keep the 1st 2, for example.

Note that this is also 10% faster than the other answers, so far (in FF 5).  [See this performance test](http://jsperf.com/select-all-but-first).

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div").getElementsByClassName("c1");
for (var i = 1; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

I hope it works