# Hide one Element when duplicate DIV is existing

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to hide one element when a duplicate element in existing.

```
<div class="example">Example</div>
<-- Lot of code here -->
<div class="example">Example</div> <!-- Hide this with CSS: display: none; -->
```

I think i need a Script

Comment: This has been answered already - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895197/hide-all-divs-except-first-one-having-same-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little more complex answer. Following solution will catch **all** elements in your document that have a `class` attribute. It will count the amount of every element with specified class and will hide **every** element with the same class **except** the first one.

```js
var allElems = document.querySelectorAll('*'),
    elems = [],
    obj = {};
    
    Array.from(allElems).forEach(v => v.getAttribute('class') ? elems.push(v) : null);
    elems.forEach(v => !obj[v.getAttribute('class')] ? obj[v.getAttribute('class')] = 1 :     obj[v.getAttribute('class')]++);
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(v) {
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(v);
      if (obj[v] > 1) {
        Array.from(elements).forEach(v => v.hidden = true);
        elements[0].hidden = false;
      }
    });
```

```html
<div class="example">Example</div>
<div class="example">Example</div>
<div class="example">Example</div>
<div class="example">Example</div>

<div class="another">Another</div>
<div class="another">Another</div>

<div class="Alone">Alone</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your structure will be like that always with the elements as siblings you can use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

```css
.example ~ .example {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">Example</div>
<p>More code between siblings</p>
<div class="example">Example</div> <!-- Hide this with CSS: display: none; -->
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide all divs with the class "example" except for the first div with that class you could use this jQuery,

```
$('.example:gt(0)').css('display','none');
```

Sets all divs with class "example" explicitly to `display:none;` with an index greater than 0.