# hide duplicate element with unique classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

there are two separate sections on a post archive page.
first section displays two featured posts.  the div class for each post is unique to the page being displayed.  EX:

```
<div class"featured">
<div class="featured-post post-1234"> post content </div>
<div class="featured-post post-9999"> post content </div>
</div>
```

The second section displays the full list of posts in this category.

```
<div class="feed">
<div class="post-grid-post post-9999"> post content </div>
<div class="post-grid-post post-1111"> post content </div>
<div class="post-grid-post post-3333"> post content </div>
 </div>
```

I would like to hide a post from the second section if it is already displayed in the first. Having trouble since I am not targeting just one class but multiple.

I have  tried the suggestion here, but it is breaking my page because it is searching the whole page since i havent figured out how to target the parent divs only [Hide one Element when duplicate DIV is existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328473/hide-one-element-when-duplicate-div-is-existing)

```
var allElems = document.querySelectorAll('*'),
    elems = [],
    obj = {};
    
    Array.from(allElems).forEach(v => v.getAttribute('class') ? elems.push(v) : null);
    elems.forEach(v => !obj[v.getAttribute('class')] ? obj[v.getAttribute('class')] = 1 :     obj[v.getAttribute('class')]++);
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(v) {
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(v);
      if (obj[v] > 1) {
        Array.from(elements).forEach(v => v.hidden = true);
        elements[0].hidden = false;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Why do you need to fix this via JavaScript "after the fact", why is the query that fetches the data for that second section, not excluding either featured posts in general, or if there is more featured posts than just the two you have shown in the first section, those two post IDs specifically?

Comment: I agreed with @CBroe here that try to do it in query of fetching post only otherwise even after hiding you can face issue in pagination too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can achieve it easily

a) Loop over `featured-post` div and get its last class

b) Hide `post-grid-post` div which contains the same class.

Working snippet:

```js
jQuery('.featured-post').each(function(){
    var classVal = jQuery(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    jQuery(".post-grid-post."+classVal).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class"featured">
<div class="featured-post post-1234"> post content </div>
<div class="featured-post post-9999"> post content </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="feed">
<div class="post-grid-post post-9999"> post content </div>
<div class="post-grid-post post-1111"> post content </div>
<div class="post-grid-post post-3333"> post content </div>
 </div>
```

Note: since you are having WordPress website so use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: perfect, thanks!